# Android StudioのDevice File Explorerでアップロードしたファイルが壊れやすい?

Tags: android, sqlite

アンドロイドアプリのデバッグをしているのですが困った事があります。

1. Android 上のアプリでsqliteのデータベースを作成し、データを書き込み
2. 作成したsqliteのデータベースファイルをAndroid StudioのDevice File ExplorerでWindows PCにコピー
3. そのファイルをA5 SQL、またはPupSQLiteで中のデータの書き換え
4. Android StudioのDevice File Explorerで元のファイルを削除してUpload
5. Androidアプリからデータベースにアクセスするとdenied{open}となってファイルが開けない事が多い

どうもAndroid->WindowsだとSQLiteのファイルをコピーしても中はちゃんと操作できるのですが、逆にWindows->AndroidだとSQLiteのファイルをAndroidでは認識できない事が多いです。

[SQLiteデータベースの参照方法](https://site-studio.noratoki.com/sqlite%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E5%8F%82%E7%85%A7%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95) を参考にAndroid内蔵のsqlite3でアクセスしてみたのですが、アップロードする度に

1. xxx.db3 not database file
2. DBファイルには接続できるがselect分を発行してもどのテーブル、ビューも no such tableとなる
3. ちゃんとアクセスできる

と、状態が変わっていきます(順番になるわけでは無くてランダムっぽいですが)

Device File Explorerはそんなにファイル転送に失敗しやすいのでしょうか。
検索してもそんな事を書いている人がいないのですが・・・

Comment: 検索して出てくるこんなツールで調べられるか試してみてはどうでしょう？ [Free SQLite Viewer Tool](https://www.freeviewer.org/sqlite/), [DB Browser for SQLite](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/library/software/sqldbbrowser/), [SQLite Viewer Web App](https://sqliteviewer.app/), [SQLite Viewer](https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/), [https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/](https://www.systoolsgroup.com/sqlite-viewer.html)

Comment: いくつか試してみたのですが同じファイルでも成功したり失敗したりするのは変わりませんでした
Android Studioのインストールに失敗したのかも?
とりあえずコマンドラインでしばらくやってみます

Comment: 解決のためではなく、問題があったときにファイルの何処が壊れたりおかしくなったのかを調べるための手段として提示してみました。それがわかればその現象を引き起こしているのが何なのか調べることにつながるのでは？と思っています。

Comment: ファイルの何処が壊れるのかがよくわからないのです・・・
同じファイルを同じようにアップロードしても、全く問題なかったり、ファイルを認識しなかったり、ファイルは認識できるけどテーブルが見つからなかったりと・・・

とりあえずAndroidエミュレーターにSqlite3がデフォルトで入っているのでそれでデバッグする事にしました